# Find Methods in derived classes with ActiveRecord - Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a class that derives from ActiveRecord::Base.
This class has a subclass that is differentiated in the database by a type id column.
How do I make sure that all the inherited active record functions in the derived classes append the type_id column to the conditions hash on any queries that are executed by the derived class?  Are there any kind of "before" functions that I could override to inject a condition into the process for the derived classes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your column was called "type", ActiveRecord would do this automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks - this works great when I changed to a column called type.  ActiveRecord puts the name of the model into the type column for each object.

Comment: If you don't wish to change the column name then you can also use the set_inheritance_column declaration

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is called Single Table Inheritance (STI).  That's why what Radar said about your column being called type works.